# View.postDelayed why is it an instance method?

Tags: android

In Android platform, a View object has an instance method [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29), which according to the documentation:

> Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue, to be run after
>   the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the
>   user interface thread.

My questions:

1. Why this method has to be an instance method of View?
2. Would it be different if I call postDelayed in one view instead of another?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it should not be an instance method of view ?? Instance variables help in creating multiple objects that can be handled, but with static you cant achieve that. Imagine if ImageView is static then you cannot have more than one image holder in your applications.

Comment: Assuming that postDelayed behave exactly the same when I call it from one view instead of another, then I don't think this method belongs to any one particular view instance. It should be factored out somewhere. And because it "Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue", I thought it really should belong to this message queue instance, like messageQueue.postDelayed or something.

Comment: The message queue in this case would be the queue that modifies the UI. Check this for the time being http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html, reply you tomorrow bye

Comment: Can you be a bit more elaborate on what your asking, and what do you mean by "when I call it from one view instead of another"

Comment: I agree. It feels weird to have this on a View.  I'd expect to, at the very least, have a getHandler() method that I would call postDelayed on. As it is, this method is really a helper (ala findViewById) that simply forwards the call to it's mAttachInfo member.

Answer (score 2):

> Why this method has to be an instance method of View?

It references an `mAttachInfo` data member, in its current implementation, and in turn to that data member's `mHandler`, which is a `Handler` that actually does the `postDelayed()` work (if `mAttachInfo` is not `null`). You are welcome to read all of this in [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java).

> Would it be different if I call postDelayed in one view instead of another?

In theory, two `View` instances could work with separate `Handler` instances. However, from the standpoint of the documented behavior, there should be no difference.